# I am confused in the way Vue.js works

Tags: javascript, html, function, vue.js, object

```
const vm = Vue.createApp({

    data(){

        return{
            
            firstname: "tanner",
            lastname: "die"
        }
    },
    methods:{
        fullname(){
            return `${this.firstname} ${this.lastname.toUpperCase()}`
        }
    }

}).mount("#app")
```

1. How exactly is data a function was it predefined or does Vue know that its a function.
2. Is methods an object or a function and if its an object why dont we say `{{methods.fullname()}}` when were displaying it in HTML.

Comment: > Under the hood Vue will walk through all the properties that we define into the data and converts them to getter/setters using Object.defineProperty.
see [demistyfing vue internals](https://medium.com/js-imaginea/the-vue-js-internals-7b76f76813e3). btw, your fullname is usually declared as a "computed" property.

Comment: @zangab The comment applies to Vue 2 while the question uses 3

Comment: @EstusFlask he uses the options API which afaik didnt change conceptionally.